# Serializing using XMLEncoder in java

Tags: java, xml-serialization

After an hour of going through the wikis and conventions of using `XMLEncoder` in Java, I stil can't make any progress of serialising my `SystemSnapshot` class using XMLEncoder. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong? My resources are as follows :

```
package core;

import gui.SceneManager;
import java.io.Serializable;

/**
 *
 * @author Subhra
*/

public class SystemSnapshot implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -6637378268413872760L;

private final School school;

private final User[] users;

private final String colorName;

public SystemSnapshot(){
    school = SessionManager.getSchool();
    users = UserStore.getUsers();
    colorName = SceneManager.getColor();
}

public SystemSnapshot(School school, User[] users, String c) {
    this.school = school;
    this.users = users;
    this.colorName = c;
}

public School getSchool() {
    return school;
}

public User[] getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public String getColorName() {
    return colorName;
}

}
```

No errors in the terminal. But the output is like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<java version="1.8.0_40" class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
<object class="core.SystemSnapshot"/>
</java>
```

Anyone?

After jtahlborn's answer i figured out and added all getters and setters. Now i'm getting two types of outputs.
Case 1 :

```
XMLEncoder xml = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream("try.xml"));
School ss = new School("S");
ss.addSubject(new Subject("BEnals"));
ss.addTeacher(new Teacher("Nil","T0",21,5000,new Subject("S")));
ss.addClass(new Standard(1,1));
ss.addStudent("STU0");
User u = new User(UserType.ADMIN,"Subhra","subhra","itsveryconfidential");
SystemSnapshot ss2 = new SystemSnapshot(ss,new User[]{u},"A string");
xml.writeObject(ss2);
xml.close();
```

is producing the right output. Whereas
Case 2 :

```
XMLEncoder oos = new XMLEncoder(new FileOutputStream("data.base"));
SystemSnapshot ss = new   SystemSnapshot(SessionManager.getSchool(),UserStore.getUsers(),SceneManager.getColor());
oos.writeObject(ss);
oos.close();
```

is still producing the output shown above. What to do?

**Source Code for `SessionManager` and `UserStore`**

**SessionManager.java**

```
package core;

import core.User.UserType;
public class SessionManager {

private static User currentuser;

private static School school;

public static void setSchool(School schol) {
     school = schol;
}

public static School getSchool() {
    return school;
}

public static User getCurrentuser() {
    return currentuser;
}

public static void setCurrentuser(User currentuser) {
    SessionManager.currentuser = currentuser;
}

public static UserType getCurrentUserType(){
    return currentuser.getType();
}

}
```

**UserStore.java**

```
package core;

public class UserStore {

private static User[] users = new User[0];

public static User[] getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public static void setUsers(User[] users) {
    UserStore.users = users;
}

public static void addUser(User u) {
    users = new BIO<User>().addToArray(users,u);
}

public static void removeUser(User u) {
    users = new BIO<User>().removeFromArray(users,u);
}

public static User getUser(String username){
    for(User u : users){
        if(u.getUsername().equals(username)){
            return u;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Just a tip, if it's an option for you: Using the [Simple XML framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) really saves a lot of time for XML serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and i've downloaded it. But it's taking a near about 2.5mbs of space where my program is not more than a mb. So, i don't wanna use that. Do you know any other lightweights?

Comment: Well, the download package is 2.5mb (with source, docs, etc.), but the Jar itself is just 430kb.

Comment: Whoa! It's really annoying to add that much annotations.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that your SystemSnapshot is not a valid java bean because it doesn't have setters for your properties. the XMLEncoder doesn't do the same magic that normal serialization does, it requires valid java beans (getters and setters for all properties).

Comment: I got it. But now a new problem arises. See the edit.

Comment: @Subhranil - tough to know without knowing the contents of the methods being called.

Comment: Well, as their name says, the SessionManager class has some methods to store the data from saved database to memory. It has a method named     `setSchool` which stores a static instance of the school within SessionManager, and the corresponding get method does the reverse. While the `UserStore` class buffers an User[] from physical storage to memory. Do you need to see the classes? @jtahlborn

Comment: @Subhranil - if you want help with your code, you are going to have to show it.  how do expect help with stuff no one can see?

Comment: @Subhranil - do you ever set the values in the SessionManager, UserStore and SceneManager?

Comment: Yup obviously. I've even passed the new `School` and `User` instances in those respective methods and still none of the `get` methods have worked in the new instance of `SystemSnapshot`. And for `SceneManager`, the `getColor()` always returns a pre-assigned static string, "Grey". Dont know what's happening out there. \:

Comment: However, the `ObjectOutputStream` is perfectly serialising `SystemSnapshot`. `XMLEncoder` is the problem. Is it any bug of JDK_1.8.40?

Comment: @Subhranil - unfortunately, i don't think there's any more help i can give you based on the code you have shown.  so, either you could create a SCCSE which shows the problem, or you could step through your current code with a debugger and see where the disconnect is.  (i would recommend the latter if you haven't done that yet).

Comment: What's SCCSE by the way?